# How to get average of earliest datetime per day?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to get average time based on their earliest check in for each day.

For example, these are my check in datetime.

```
Person | Checkin
-----------------
Jack    2022-01-06 16:42:34.000
Jack    2022-01-06 17:30:34.000
Jack    2022-01-07 10:22:34.000
Jack    2022-01-07 12:12:54.000
Jack    2022-01-08 11:08:53.000
```

When I want to calculate my average check in time based on earliest check in, I should only consider these datetime.

```
2022-01-06 16:42:34.000
2022-01-07 10:22:34.000
2022-01-08 11:08:53.000
```

This is my current sql to get the average check in time. But this consider all the datetime above and gets the average time.

```
Select Person,(CAST(DATEADD(SS, AVG(CAST(DATEDIFF(SS, '00:00:00', CAST(Checkin AS TIME)) AS BIGINT)), '00:00:00' ) AS TIME)) AS 'AvgCheckInTime' from #Tab_CheckIn
group by Person
```

How can I only consider the earliest datetime for each day and get the average time?

Answer (score 1):

This is a little messy.

Firstly you need to group the data to get the earliest checkin my day. That's quite simple, using `CONVERT` to `date` and `MIN`.

Then you need to get the "average" of those times. You can't *average* a `time` in SQL Server, however, as `time` represents a point in time during the day *not* an interval, so it doesn't make sense to average them like it would a timespan. As a result you need to "convert" the values to a numerical value.

In this case I use `DATEDIFF` to get the number of seconds since midnight to the checkin converted to a `time`. Then I can average those values, and finally add those second to midnight:

```sql
WITH Earliest AS(
    SELECT Person,
           MIN(Checkin) AS EarliestCheckin
    FROM dbo.YourTable
    GROUP BY Person,
             CONVERT(date,Checkin))
SELECT Person,
       DATEADD(SECOND,AVG(DATEDIFF(SECOND,'00:00',CONVERT(time,EarliestCheckin))),CONVERT(time,'00:00')) AS AverageCheckin
FROM Earliest
GROUP BY Person;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you get desired result(except filtering the undesired dates)

```
Select t.Person,(CAST(DATEADD(SS, AVG(CAST(DATEDIFF(SS, '00:00:00', CAST(t.Checkin AS TIME)) AS BIGINT)), '00:00:00' ) AS TIME)) AS 'AvgCheckInTime'
from (SELECT Person, min(Checkin) as Checkin FROM #Tab_CheckIn
      GROUP BY Person, cast(Checkin As Date)) t
group by t.Person
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Person,(CAST(DATEADD(SS, AVG(CAST(DATEDIFF(SS, '00:00:00', CAST(Checkin AS TIME)) AS BIGINT)), '00:00:00' ) AS TIME)) AS 'AvgCheckInTime'
from (
SELECT person, checkin, row_number() over(PARTITION by person, CAST(checkin as DATE) order by checkin asc) as row 
FROM #Tab_CheckIn) as p
where p.row =1
group by p.person
```